# Apache load balancing with websockets

Tags: apache, load-balancing

We want to load balance the requests between two processes listening on different ports on a KVM.

When I put the URL directly in the RewriteRule without load balancing, then everything seems to work fine. So I think there is a problem with my configuration.

My config is:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c> 
    <virtualHost :443>
    ServerName super.secret.domain

    Header add Set-Cookie "ROUTEID=.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/" env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED
    <Proxy balancer://httprewrite>
            BalancerMember http://192.168.122.83:81/$1 route=1
            BalancerMember http://192.168.122.83:80/$1 route=2
            ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEID
    </Proxy>

    <Proxy balancer://wsrewrite>
            BalancerMember ws://192.168.122.83:81/$1 route=1
            BalancerMember ws://192.168.122.83:80/$1 route=2
            ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEID
    </Proxy>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.) balancer://wsrewrite/ [P,L] 

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket [NC] 
    RewriteRule /(.*) balancer://httprewrite/ [P,L] 

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/super.secret.domain/cert.pem 
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/super.secret.domain/privkey.pem Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/super.secret.domain/chain.pem 
    </virtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Some parts are loading some other parts not. For example https://super.secret.domain/favicon.ico gives a 404 error.